# GPS data management software

Tags: maps, gps, electronic-gear

Is there any good software to manage GPS tracks and POI efficiently that you would recommend? My dream would be an offline computer based (macOS and Windows) software, with a modern GUI, which allows a multi-level structure as Base Camp does, with meta-data search and the ability to display offline (OSM, GMAP as a wish, it is probably proprietary) and online maps (OSM).

I am currently using Garmin Base Camp and MyMaps in Google Maps for sharing routes and POI with other persons. Both lacks of some key functions:

- Base Camp: No batch export of tracks with the file structure, no good meta data search, no integration of online maps (Apple Plan, Google Maps...), ergonomics and GUI from another century
- MyMaps: Online only (export as KML possible, sync with Google Earth App is not working well, and the ergonomics in Google Earth is terrible), only one level of hierarchy, import of track in a separate layer (not possible to import a track in the active layer).

What software (computer based, no App for smartphone or tablet) for managing GPS tracks fulfill these criteria? And if there are multiple, what are their respective (dis-)advantages?

Comment: OziExplorer (http://www.oziexplorer.com) was one I used 15-20 years ago and found very good back then.  I believe its still current and would certainly be worth a look.

Comment: Might be a better fit on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have a look at QGIS. It's an open source Desktop GIS software with lots of functionality. Might be overkill for your tasks though.

Comment: Better at https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I had a look in QGIS, it seams to be an overkill, but very interesting. OziExplorer is a bit old from the look and feel, I am not ready to give 100$ out for a tool that has no mordern GUI (I am perfectly ready to buy a software). I did not know the Software Recommendations on Stackexchange, it might effectively be the right one.

Comment: Re: softwarerecs:  Generally very poor results.  Most questions don't have answers, Not many upvotes.

Comment: https://showgps.de ; or try https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSMTracker_(Android) if adding a bluetooth keyboard with touchpad would convince you that android can be part of the answer you are looking for.

Comment: +1 for QGIS. It's deep, but if you're looking for full manual control over your data display & usage, a legit GIS is the only way.

Comment: I've been pretty happy with using Gaia (https://www.gaiagps.com/) on my desktop, via browser. The online interface can load/save GPS tracks from all the major formats (GPX, KML/KMZ, GeoJSON, etc.). Main downside for your request is it is online-only.

If you change your mind and want mobile apps too, their apps are fairly decent. Along with my Instinct on my wrist, I use Gaia + Trailforks + OnXHunt as my main hiking/mtb/horse guidance, and then upload my Instinct track into Gaia for storing.